# How should I go about adding an autoscroll to this Carousel that can be intervened by the user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I'm developing a "slideshow" of text boxes that currently can be scrolled using arrow buttons. I would like the slideshow to auto scroll **only until** the user intervenes by clicking one of the arrow buttons.

Here's the relevant state logic in the React component (which I've defined as a function, not a class):

```
// Maintain a variable of the currently selected slide
const [slide, setSlide] = useState(0);

// Go to the next slide
function nextSlide() {
  if (slide == companies.length - 1) {
    setSlide(0);
  } else {
    setSlide(slide + 1)
  }
}
```

The arrows will set the current slide using the `setSlide` function. The auto scroll I believe would best be handled by registering a call to `nextSlide` using `setTimeout`.

This works fine. `setTimeout` calls `nextSlide`, `nextSlide` causes a re-render, which then causes a new `nextSlide` to be registered and it goes on and on as expected. The issue is I can't figure out how to handle the "user intervention" aspect.

My first thought was to add an `intervention` boolean to the component state that gets set to `true` when the user clicks an arrow, and then having `nextSlide` only perform its logic if this boolean is set to false. After trying this, it seems that the `nextSlide` call registered in `setTimeout` has its own separate state instance, because the boolean is always `false`, even after I click an arrow.

Am I doing this improperly? is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Mission accomplished with the following code. The key was `useRef`:

```
const intervention = useRef(false)

setInterval(() => {
  if (!intervention.current) {
    nextSlide();
  }
}, 8000);
```